# Getting the value for a textfield from a VBA variable

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have a Form in wich I enter some values (project info)

[image: ProjectInfo]

The values entered in these fields, are stored in some variables in VBA when the user clicks the button:

```
Private Sub btnPItoKabels_Click()

    Dim Project As String
    Dim ProjectNummer As String
    Dim OpdrachtGever As String

    Project = ProjectInvoer.Value
    ProjectNummer = ProjectNrInvoer.Value
    OpdrachtGever = OpdrachtgeverInvoer.Value

    DoCmd.OpenForm "frmMain", acNormal, , , acFormAdd
    DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmProjectInvoer", acSaveNo

End Sub
```

Now I would like to retrieve these values in a few reports I have (they will appear in the header)

[image: Header]

These are just regular text fields.

How can I retrieve the values from the three strings and put them in these fields?

Comment: Your question is not quite clear, do you wish to store these values in a table, do a series of reports run on the back of you clicking this form's `OK` button? How is it the Reports relate to this form?

Comment: @MattDonnan the first picture is a Form in wich a user can insert the project info, the reports are related to the form in that the reports that are printed have a header in wich I want the project info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done the following to solve the problem:

when pressing the "ok" button, the values in the form will be put in a new table "tempProjectInfo"

When loading the reports, the values are taken from the table and the table is dropped.

Answer (score 1):

It's not easy to say which setup will work best for you, I suggest amending your `OK` button to run the reports in question.

In your reports design set for example the **Project** header field to:

```
=Forms!frmProjectInvoer!ProjectInvoer
```

This will then reference the values entered in your form when you open your reports, note you do not need to add the **.Value** to the end of the fieldname

Answer (score 1):

If your form is not closed, you can easily reference them with the formula "=Forms!MyFormName!Project" (or whichever textbox you're referencing).  If you plan to close the form, you can't really reference the values unless you specify them as GLOBAL, but even so they only last while the current sub is running.